# QTreeWidgetItem::insertChild does not its work

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I have a `QTreeWidget` and I would like to insert a child at a certain index. I tried with

```
void QTreeWidgetItem::insertChild ( int index, QTreeWidgetItem * child )
```

but any index I put, it inserts the child at the end of all children the parent has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution:

My first code was this

```
QTreeWidgetItem* newVtxItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(parentItem);
newVtxItem->setText(0, "vtx 1");
newVtxItem->setText(1, "-1");
childOfNameProfile->insertChild(0,newVtxItem);
```

Then I correct it by deleting the parentItem of the new QTreeWidgetItem in this way:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* newVtxItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
newVtxItem->setText(0, "vtx 1");
newVtxItem->setText(1, "-1");
childOfNameProfile->insertChild(0,newVtxItem);
```

The reason why the child was inserted after all children is because when you create a QTreeWidgetItem and defining a parent, Qt put it directly at the end of the children list of the parent. So insertChild, as the documentation said:

> ```
> If the child has already been inserted somewhere else it won’t be inserted again.
> ```

I hope I could help someone. Enjoy Qt!

Comment: Just a Note: You can accept your own Anwser so that other know that you found your solution.